# `ng-click` not calling the controller function some times

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I have 2 popup's which is controller by a service in  a page. on click on the `div` element i am calling the `controller` function. after i added the 2nd `popup` directive especially some times the `ng-click` not working properly. how to solve this?

here is my service.js

```
"use strict";
angular.module("tcpApp").service("modalService", function ( $rootScope) {

    //header configuration

    $rootScope.hideModal = function() {

        $rootScope.showModal = false;

    };

    this.changePass = function ( configId ) {

        $rootScope.showModal = true; //this is for global 
        $rootScope.currentConfigPopView = 'views/tools/'+configId+'.html';
        $rootScope.$apply();

    };

    this.showSummary = function () {

        this.showSummaryPop = true;

    }

    this.hideSummary = function () {

        this.showSummaryPop = false; //this is within controller


    }

});
```

html:

```
<div class="statusBoard board8" ng-click='modal.showSummary("board8")'>

                                <span><img src="../images/iconDetails.png" alt="icon plan and actual"></span>
                                <h2>{{boardAssets.board8.title}}</h2>

                                <span class="row dwo">
                                    <span class="catg">Total Issue Reported</span>
                                    <span class="cd issueData">{{contractor.IssueDetails.TotalIssue}}</span>
                                </span>
                                <span class="row mas">
                                    <span class="catg">Issue Resolved</span>
                                    <span class="cd resolveData">{{contractor.IssueDetails.IssueResolved}}</span>
                                </span>
                                <span class="row rfi">
                                    <span class="catg">Issue Remaining</span>
                                    <span class="cd remainData">{{contractor.IssueDetails.IssueRemaining}}</span>
                                </span>

                            </div>
<body-footer></body-footer>
<config-popup></config-popup> //after i added this directive getting ng-click issue.
<modal-popup></modal-popup>
```

config popup html:

```
<div class='ng-modal' ng-if="showModal">
    <div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'></div>
        <div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'>
        <div class='ng-modal-dialog-content'>

         <ng-include src="currentConfigPopView"></ng-include>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could we see the code for config-popup?

Comment: @alcfeoh config popup html added

Comment: It would be useful to have a Fiddle or the entire code for that. We're still missing pieces.

Comment: out of 10 refresh, 1 time the `ng-click` not working. this is very hard to reproduce in fiddle

Comment: If it happens erratically, then it's a sync issue that happens when some code is loaded too early. Do you use any jQuery plugin or other UI element that is initialized "manually" with a JS function?

Comment: I am not using any jQuery plugin.  what you mean my UI element that is initialied "manually"?